# Change div text (and revert back) on tab button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tabs like below image

[image]

On selection of tab i want to change the text of a div. If i select invoice i want to change value of credit card fee to 0 and if i select credit card it's value should revert back.(in above image it's $17.00)

Here is my html code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs payment-method-list" style="list-style-type: none;">    
    <li class="active" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <a data-target="#payment-method-selector-creditcard" data-toggle="tab" data-type="creditcard" href="#">
            Credit / Debit Card
        </a>
    </li>   
    <li class="" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <a data-target="#payment-method-selector-invoice" data-toggle="tab" data-type="invoice" href="#">
            Invoice
        </a>
    </li>   
</ul>   
<p>
```

Credit card fee code

```
<span class="pull-right cart-summary-handling-cost-formatted" id="service_charge">$17.00</span>     //it's value will be dynamic        
<span>Credit Card Fee </span>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".payment-method-list li a").click(function() {
        var originaltext = jQuery("#service_charge").text();
        if (jQuery('a[data-target="#payment-method-selector-invoice "]').parent().hasClass('active')) {
            jQuery("#service_charge").text("0");
        } else {
            jQuery("#service_charge").text(originaltext);
        }

    });
});
```

But it's changing value to 0 when i click first invoice then credit card after that it's value is not changing back to original text.

As I'm new to jquery please help me what's wrong with this code.

Comment: How the input `service_charge` is populated?

Comment: It's value is dynamic. using a function to generate it's value.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".payment-method-list li a").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("originalBalance", jQuery("#service_charge").text());
        if (jQuery('a[data-target="#payment-method-selector-invoice "]').parent().hasClass('active')) {
            jQuery("#service_charge").text("0");
        } else {
            jQuery("#service_charge").text(localStorage.getItem("originalBalance"));
        }
    });
});
```

Try this. I am saving the original balance through localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Try check by `data-type` ,because your `active` class is changing when you clicked and checking your operator ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var originaltext= jQuery("#service_charge").text();    
    jQuery(".payment-method-list li a").click(function(){    
    if(jQuery(this).data("type") == "invoice")
        {
        jQuery("#service_charge").text("0");
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#service_charge").text(originaltext);
    }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Working fine...one question can this code run without clicking on tab just on page load? I have tried it without clicking but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the issue as once the text on input is updated when using `.text()`, next time it will return the updated text. You can to persist the `originaltext` in internal data cache using `.data()`, which can be fetched when required.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {      
    //Persists originaltext
    var serviceChange = jQuery("#service_charge");      
    var originaltext = serviceChange.text();
    serviceChange.data('originaltext', originaltext);

    //Populate it using the method
    //serviceChange.data('originaltext', getOriginalText());      

    jQuery(".payment-method-list li a").click(function() {            
        if (jQuery('a[data-target="#payment-method-selector-invoice "]').parent().hasClass('active')) {
            serviceChange.text("0");
        } else {
            serviceChange.text(serviceChange.data('originaltext'));
        }

    });
});
```